# dyld: Symbol not found: AppIntentsShortcutsBuilder

Tags: swift, xcode, appintents

This happened suddenly after installing Xcode 15.3. Both simulator and actual device on versions other than iOS 17.4 (e.g. 17.2, my minimum deployment target) are crashing on start. It's working fine on iOS 17.4. The error message is this:

`dyld[2687]: Symbol not found: _$s10AppIntents0A16ShortcutsBuilderO10buildBlockySayAA0A8ShortcutVGAGd_tFZ Referenced from: <CAAA4ECB-9E8B-3089-BAA3-30353A952A4F> /Users/abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/855CEC69-3F94-4A57-99DA-23000B104AC5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F72ABCFE-4B85-461E-9B1D-4589DAB9262F/MyApp.app/MyApp Expected in:     <6683DFEB-450B-3643-B865-E4D9D0B501D6> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21C62/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.2.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/AppIntents.framework/AppIntents`

The issue is gone if I comment out my Shortcuts related code (it's only a few lines):

```
import Intents
import SwiftData
import AppIntents

struct MyAppIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "doSomething"

    @Parameter(title: "myParam")
    var myParam: URL

    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        // perform task here ...
        return .result()
    }

    static var parameterSummary: some ParameterSummary {
        Summary("Summary")
    }
}

struct MyAppShortcuts: AppShortcutsProvider {
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: MyAppIntent(),
            phrases: ["MyAppIntent"],
            shortTitle: "MyAppIntent",
            systemImageName: "play.rectangle.fill"
        )
    }
}
```

There are no additional frameworks installed, I've cleaned build folders and restarted everything multiple times. It's also happening on the TestFlight version.

Anything I could try to fix this?

Comment: same here `Symbol not found: _$s10AppIntents0A16ShortcutsBuilderO10buildBlockySayAA0A8ShortcutVGAGd_tFZ` when using Xcode 15.3 and deploying to device < iOS 17.4

Comment: Not that this is helpful, but chiming in to say I also have this in one project, not in others that have many intents. The intent itself seems fine, but if I include the AppShortcutsProvider, it crashes on startup on anything less than 17.4.

Comment: @agiletortoise are you saying it happens only in some projects, even though all of them have an `AppShortcutsProvider`, or is it only happening in the ones that do?

Comment: Yes. It's clearly the same issue that Xcode 15.3 visionOS builds have running on visionOS 1.0, as mentions here: https://mastodon.social/@stroughtonsmith/112044268362724143